# Were AO's abilities intended or not?

Tags: noor

In the novella *Noor* by Nnedi Okorafor, the protagonist, AO, has the ability to control virtually any technology. This is possibly a consequence of the implants that Ultimate Corporation gave her as part of a long game to produce babies with congenital issues who could be used for testing their implants.

However, given how terrified they were of her having this ability even before she started to use it against them, it seems possible that they did not anticipate her abilities. And of course, as usual in Okorafor's works, one cannot rule out the possibility that AO's powers have an explicitly supernatural component, one unrelated or loosely related to Ultimate's technology.

Did Ultimate Corporation *expect* AO to have technopathic abilities when they plotted to give her implants? Or was that an unintentional effect?